# Is there a chance for app to get rejected from App store?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an application in App store that is designed to control a hardware device using an HTTP server and WiFi router in the device.
Now I am planning to release another version of the same application with an extra scheduling feature. That is an extra tab will be added to the application. And I am planning to release this as a separate application in Appstore. I will use the same app icon and except one I am planning to use the same screen shots for all the other screens.
Now I doubt if there is any chance for the app to get rejected at the time of submission to app store. I could not find a specific answer from Apple develper sites. Please share youe thoughts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple approval process (ask Apple).

Comment: Why not just update the existing app?

Comment: My client needs the app to be submitted as a separate app. May be its his business logic. IF there is some solid points proving the app has a chance to get rejected I can ask him to release the app as an update OR make the feature enabled with In app purchase.

Comment: You should recommend that anyway, it's the right thing to do...

Comment: yes. But before recommending this I need to confirm if there is a chance. Are there any such existing apps in App store?

Comment: The duplicate icon and screenshots *may* be an issue ... could mislead .. is it a free app ?

Comment: There's always a chance that your app will be rejected.

Comment: Why post a 2nd app? Just update the existing app but make the additional tab a feature that can be added via in-app purchase.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is always a chance that your app will be rejected. Sometimes the reasons will seem random and arbitrary. Things like connecting to an insecure (unencrypted) web server may be considered sufficient grounds. The [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) is a good place to start, but even if you are compliant the decision to include your app or not is ultimately Apples.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Should have done more research before posting the question.

App store Review Guideline says:

2.11: Apps that duplicate apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra apps

So there is always a chance that my app get rejected.